# Attempting to build a table completely on the fly with Tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I am attempting to work with the TableSorter jQuery plugin to build a table completely on the fly (headers and data).

As is the case with most web applications, the user inputs some data/criteria, clicks a button, and data is returned. I build a table to hold the data, which the user can sort.
I had that working fine, however, it was decided that we need the users to be able to specify what columns of data they would like and in what order those columns should be.

The data retrieval is completely done. I make a javascript/jQuery call from the aspx page to the aspx.vb code-behind via a web method. The code behind interacts with a DLL 
which passes its information back in a datatable. I build a string from the datatable to pass back to the javascript/jQuery code. In the javascript the string is split into a
string array.

Here is how I was building the table previously (before the requirements of user specified columns and column order):

HTML:

```
<table id="mytable" class="tablesorter" border="1">
       <thead title="Click to sort">
        <tr>
        <th style="color:#A7C942;" title="Click for default order"><div class="1"></div></th>
        <th><div id="div1" class="2">Column2</div></th>
        <th><div class="3">Column3</div></th>
        <th><div class="4">Column4</div></th>
        <th><div class="5">Column5</div></th>
        <th><div class="6">Column6</div></th>
        <th><div class="7">Column7</div></th>
        <th><div class="8">Column8</div></th>
        <th><div class="9">Column9</div></th>
        <th><div class="10">Column10</div></th>
        <th><div class="11">Column11</div></th>
        <th><div class="12">Column12</div></th>
        <th><div class="13">Column13</div></th>
        <th><div class="14">Column14</div></th>
        <th><div class="15">Column15</div></th>
        <th><div class="16">Column16</div></th>
        <th><div class="17">Column17</div></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
           <tbody>

           </tbody>
       </table>
```

Javascript:

```
var table = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= NumberOfRecords; i++) { //for each record
   if (i % 2 == 0) { table += '<tr class="even">'; } else {
       table += '<tr>';
   }


   table += '<td><div class="1"><img src="/resources/ic_menu_search.png" alt="" height="20" width="20" style="cursor: pointer;" id="' + i + '" ></img></div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="2">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 1] + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="3">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 4] + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="4">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 5] + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="5">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 6] + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="6">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 9] + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="7">' + "$" + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 12] + ".00" + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="8">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 15] + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="9">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 16] + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="10">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 37] + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="11">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 38] + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="12">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 39] + "%" + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="13">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 45] + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="14">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 66] + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="15">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 78] + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="16">' + "$" + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 81] + ".00" + '</div></td>';
   table += '<td><div class="17">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 109] + '</div></td>';
   table += '</tr>';


  } 



$('#mytable').append(table);
```

TableSorter:

```
$('#mytable').tablesorter({
              theme: 'default',
              widgets: ['zebra', 'reorder'],
              widgetOptions: {
                  reorder_axis: 'x', // 'x' or 'xy'
                  reorder_delay: 300,
                  reorder_helperClass: 'tablesorter-reorder-helper',
                  reorder_helperBar: 'tablesorter-reorder-helper-bar',
                  reorder_noReorder: 'reorder-false',
                  reorder_blocked: 'reorder-block-left reorder-block-end',
                  reorder_complete: null // callback
              }

          })
```

I set div classes for each because the header and data weren't lining up properly since they were being created at different times. This works fine, but since the user needs to be able to determine the columns that they see and in what order, I'm going to have to approach it a bit differently. I came across the 
Build Table widget for TableSorter and attempted to implement it as follows:

HTML:

```
   <div id="mytable">
   </div>
```

Javascript (first two columns will be static, the rest will be set by the user on a setup screen):

```
   var table = [];

   table += '[ [' + ['', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6', 'Column7', 'Column8', 'Column9', 'Column10', 'Column11', 'Column12', 'Column13', 'Column14', 'Column15', 'Column16', 'Column17'] + '],';

   for (var i = 1; i <= NumberOfRecords; i++) { //for each record
      table += '[' + [i, TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 1], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 4], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 5], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 6], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 9], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 12], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 15], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 16], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 37], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 38], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 39], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 45], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 66], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 78], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 81], TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 109]] + ']';

      if (i != NumberOfRecords) {
          table += ',';
      }
   }

   table += '];'
```

TableSorter:

```
   $('#mytable').tablesorter({
              theme: 'default',
              widgets: ['zebra', 'reorder', 'stickyHeaders'],//, 'resizable'],
              widgetOptions: {
                  build_source: table,
                  build_headers: {
                      rows: 1,
                      classes: [],
                      text: [],
                      widths : ['3%', '8%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '6%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '6%']
                  }

              }

          })
```

However, this will do nothing. If I add the "$('#mytable').append(table);" it will append the text, but I still get no table. I've made sure the code for the Build Table 
widget is included in the project and if I set a breakpoint it is being hit on load.

The end goal is to read the user's column preference from a database (which will be easy) and use the selected columns to generate a table completely dynamically.
Then that table needs to be sortable, have reorderable columns (which I also have a TableSorter widget for), and the columns need to be resizable (another TableSorter widget).

How do I build this table on the fly, being able to accomplish the above goals, and have the columns line up with the data? 
What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like the `tbody` of the table needs to be targeted.

Well, it appears that `$('#mytable')` is actually targeting a table element; and since the javascript doesn't have the `thead` or `tbody` elements, the append code should look like this:

```
$('#mytable tbody').append(table);
```

As for the modified header that the user builds, I don't see that code above.

If you want to use the build widget, the `table` array above should contain an array of row arrays, currently it is building an array of one large string. Try this instead (untested):

```
var table = [];
table.push(['', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6', 'Column7', 'Column8', 'Column9', 'Column10', 'Column11', 'Column12', 'Column13', 'Column14', 'Column15', 'Column16', 'Column17']);

for (var i = 1; i <= NumberOfRecords; i++) { //for each record
    table.push([
        '<div class="1"><img src="/resources/ic_menu_search.png" alt="" height="20" width="20" style="cursor: pointer;" id="' + i + '" ></div>',
        '<div class="2">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 1] + '</div>',
        '<div class="3">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 4] + '</div>',
        '<div class="4">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 5] + '</div>',
        '<div class="5">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 6] + '</div>',
        '<div class="6">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 9] + '</div>',
        '<div class="7">$' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 12] + '.00</div>',
        '<div class="8">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 15] + '</div>',
        '<div class="9">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 16] + '</div>',
        '<div class="10">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 37] + '</div>',
        '<div class="11">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 38] + '</div>',
        '<div class="12">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 39] + '%</div>',
        '<div class="13">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 45] + '</div>',
        '<div class="14">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 66] + '</div>',
        '<div class="15">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 78] + '</div>',
        '<div class="16">$' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 81] + '.00</div>',
        '<div class="17">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 459) + 109] + '</div>'
    ]);
}

$('#myTable').tablesorter({
    theme: 'default',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders'],
    widgetOptions : {
        build_source : table,
        build_headers : {
            rows    : 1,
            classes : [],
            text    : [],
            widths : ['3%', '8%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '6%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '7%', '6%']
        },
        build_footers : {
            rows    : 0
        }
    }
});
```

Lastly, I wouldn't recommend using the reorder widget as it still in beta and has some unresolved issues before it will be production-ready. If you need to add, remove or update the table after a column has changed, use the [`updateAll` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#updateall).

Comment: I will give this a shot and get back with the results. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Right now I'm getting a JavaScript error stating that "Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'". This is occurring in the jquery.min.js file when attempting the following:

    $('#myTable').tablesorter({
    theme: 'default',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders'],
    widgetOptions : {
        build_source : table,
        build_headers : {
            rows    : 1,
            classes : [],
            text    : [],
            widths :         },
            }
});
(Removed Footer and width due to comment length restrictions)

Comment: It seems the issue is happening when the append executes. It appears to have something to do with the fact that the <tbody> section already exists in the markup. However, when I remove the markup for the <tbody> section, I get no error, but the table data is not appended either.

Comment: Which method are you using? Appending the rows, or using the build widget? They both shouldn't be used together.

Comment: Tried both. Using them together is what caused the error (my mistake), using the widget by itself isn't populating the table. In the documentation it looked like the only markup needed was a <div> with an ID the same as my table name. Tried that, to no avail. Also tried just the <table> tag and also <table> with <thead> and <tbody>, but no luck. Checked the call to the widget (also that I have a reference to it in a <script> tag). It checks out. I'll look at the doc again to see if there's anything I've missed. If you see/think of anything I may have missed, I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Could you share a link to the site or create a demo; I troubleshoot better than I can guess.

Comment: Actually, I think I have it mostly working now. It was a combination of things. Had a couple of things in the wrong order. Accidentally had a capital letter in one of my references to the table, etc. Things I should have caught. Just working with the column widths (changing the values doesn't appear to change the widths, but I may have a CSS property overriding it) and zebra striping (on table load, works after sort) now.  I'll post different questions, if needed, for those issues. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the [`widthFixed` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widthfixed) is `true` it will set the column widths by adding `<col>` tags within a `<colgroup>`.

Comment: I couldn't get the widthFixed to work for me, but I did solve the issue I was having. Basically in the table.push statement that sets the column headers, I just added a <div class="..."> that corresponded to the div class I was using for each column in the tbody. Since I won't know what columns the user has selected ahead of time, it should be easy to get the column names from the table and dynamically set the div class. Thanks again for your help, @Mottie!